# Set ImageView resource from Java

Tags: android, imageview

How to set image from android drawables at ImageView?
Not from R.drawable but from defaults... I.E. a star.
I know how to do it in xml, now I want to do the same from Java.

Comment: What is defaults?

Comment: drawables that u get with android studio :) 
btn_dialog, ic_lock_power_off,.... just needed to add android before R.drawable :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by defaults you mean drawables that are bundled with android you set them in the same way as normal drawable  eg imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync), you just prefix R with android

Comment: ah,ty :)
i typed "andr" and waited for android studio suggestion but it didnt come so i gave up. Thought it is something else :-/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to work with images at the Android environment, you have to put the images in the drawable directory, and the only way to use them in your application is using the class R. The example to set a image on android programmatically in Java is below:

```
YourImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.name_of_your_image);
```